# Pop Function In Linked List Stack Results in Segmentation Fault- C

Tags: c, linked-list, stack

I'm creating a stack using a linked list in C. The code is as follows:

```
struct node{
    int xposition;
    int yposition;
    struct node* next;
};

void pushToTop(struct node** hd, int x, int y){
    struct node* curr= *hd;
    struct node* prev=NULL;

    while(curr!=NULL){
        prev=curr;
        curr= curr->next;   
    }
    struct node* ptr= (struct node*)malloc(sizeof(struct node));
    ptr->xposition=x;
    ptr->yposition=y;
    ptr->next=curr;

    if(prev==NULL){
        *hd= ptr;}
    else{
        prev->next=ptr;
    }
}

void popFromTop(struct node** hd ){

    struct  node* curr= *hd;
    struct node* prev=NULL;
    while ( curr->next !=NULL) {
        prev=curr;
        curr=curr->next;
    }

    free(curr);
    prev->next= NULL;

}
```

The Push function works 100% of the time. The pop function works if there are multiple values in the stack, but results in a segmentation fault when there is a single value in the stack.
According to my debugger, the issue is in the popFromTop method with

```
prev->next=NULL;
```

Could someone please help me understand what the issue is?

Comment: If `prev` is NULL, you don't want to try to set `prev->next` to `NULL`. Also, if you remove the only node, you need to set `*hd` to `NULL`.

Comment: And need empty check before call `popFromTop`.

Comment: Unrelated to the actual question but why are you using the tail of the list as the top of the stack as it requires traversal of the full  list for both pop and push? That is inefficient. Use the *head* of the list as the top of the stack so that both push and pop have access to it immediately without any traversal.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As already mentioned in comments by @DavidSchwartz.
Add if condition.

```
void popFromTop(struct node** hd ){

    struct  node* curr= *hd;
    //Base condition to handle empty list
    if(*hd == NULL)
        return;

    struct node* prev=NULL;
    while ( curr->next !=NULL) {
        prev=curr;
        curr=curr->next;
    }

    free(curr);
    if(prev != NULL)
       prev->next= NULL;
    else 
       *hd = NULL;

}
```

Comment: Thank you so much! This works. I was missing the base cases and the issue @DavidSchwartz pointed out.

Answer (score 1):

If there is only one node, in pop() `prev` is always NULL. So put a condition before `prev->next = NULL`.

Also there is one more bug: if there are 0 nodes, `curr` is also NULL in pop() so you might want to handle that too.