# Why is the popping out last element in stack resulting in segmentation fault in C?

Tags: c, stack, singly-linked-list

I was creating stack operations in C .But when I was trying to pop out last element, it results in **SEGMENTATION FAULT**.

***CODE***

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

typedef struct node1
{
    int data;
    struct node1 *link;
} node;

node *top,*header;

void push()
{
    node *temp = (node *)malloc(sizeof(node));
    printf("PUSH : ");
    scanf("%d", &temp->data);
    if (header == NULL)
    {
        top = temp;
        header = temp;
        temp->link = NULL;
    }

    else
    {
        temp->link = header;
        header = temp;
        top = temp;
    }
}

void pop()
{
    if (header == NULL)
        printf("Stack Empty");
    else
    {
        node *ptr = top;
        top = header = top->link;
        free(ptr);
    }
}

void display()
{
    node *ptr = header;
    while (1)
    {
        if (ptr->link == NULL)
        {
            printf("%d", ptr->data);
            break;
        }
        printf("%d", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->link;
        printf("->");
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}

int main()
{
    printf("\nSTACK :\n\n");
            while (1)
            {
                int choice;
                printf("1.Push 2. Pop  (Press ctrl + C to exit ): ");
                scanf("%d", &choice);
                switch (choice)
                {
                case 1:
                    push();
                    display();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    pop();
                    display();
                    break;

                default:
                    printf("Wrong Entry\n\n");
                }
            }
```

}

I know a similar question [Pop Function In Linked List Stack Results in Segmentation Fault- C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39784052/pop-function-in-linked-list-stack-results-in-segmentation-fault-c) has been asked but it didn't help me. Why does this error occur?  Is the problem similar to above mentioned problem.

Comment: These declarations node *top, *rear, *front, *header; do not make a sense.

Comment: The function display can invoke undefined behavior.

Comment: @Vlad fom Moscow  edited it

Comment: What is the meaning of duplicating each other pointers top and head?

Comment: Yeah i was trying to create both stack and queue in same programme,so when trying to display i thought using a common variable as initial node in display() functon.

Comment: You need to write separate implementations of a stack and a queue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The segfault is because of your display function. In the display function you check `if (ptr->link == NULL)` but you should really be checking `if (ptr == NULL)`. As you can see, if `ptr` is `NULL`, then referencing `ptr->link` will cause a segfault.

At the beginning of your while loop in the display function you could try:
`if (ptr == NULL) break;`. Better yet, try checking if `ptr` is `NULL` as the while condition:

```
void display()
{
    node *ptr = header;
    while (ptr)
    {
        if (ptr->link == NULL)
        {
            printf("%d", ptr->data);
            break;
        }
        printf("%d", ptr->data);
        ptr = ptr->link;
        printf("->");
    }
    printf("\n\n");
}
```